# How do I share PHP class constants with Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, php, design-patterns, constants

When we pass back-end models into front-end models, sometimes there are constants that I do not want to redefine.

```
class MyModel {
    const ADMIN = 1
}
```

Usually in PHP I would access the constant this way `MyModel::ADMIN`. What is a recommended solution for bringing class constants to the front end?

Comment: You'd somehow have to include that constant in a script tag in the HTML output or in a PHP-processed JS file.

Comment: On server side you can use reflection to get constants from choosen classes and generate JavaScript file

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you should do something like this

For numbers

```
 <script>
     var MY_CONSTANT = <?php echo MyModel::ADMIN; ?>; 
 </script>
```

And for strings you should add quotes

```
 <script>
     var MY_CONSTANT = "<?php echo MyModel::ADMIN; ?>"; 
 </script>
```